# Display database data with php

Tags: php, mysql, database

The code is working, database able receives data and keeps updating through the php code.

The problem is, the data ($hb2,which is keep updating to a same row(id=1 & id=2) of table) cannot be displayed through the code shown below.

The php is call every 0.5second.

php code:

```
<?php

$hb2 =$_POST['hb'];  //fetch data from an application


// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","lala","1234","heartbeatDB");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else

echo " success connected!!<br>";

//working, database showing the data
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE heartbeatTB SET bpm='{$hb2}'   
WHERE ID=1 ");

// works too
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE heartbeatTB SET bpm='{$hb2}'    
WHERE ID=2 ");


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM heartbeatTB");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "id is >>>>" .$row['id'] ."<br>";

echo "bpm >>>> " .$row['bpm'] ."<br>show<br>";
echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've created 2 row and entered data into the row (id=3 and id=4),  and it can be display with the code.

This is the output from the php file:

```
success connected!!
id is >>>>1           
bpm >>>>               //data from database, which is keep updating**cannot display**
show

id is >>>>2
bpm >>>>               //data from database, which is keep updating**cannot display**
show

id is >>>>3           //row created byself
bpm >>>> j88 bmp
show

id is >>>>4           //row created byself
bpm >>>> 60 BPM
show
```

again, everything working fine but the displaying part.. 
any help is very appreciated

Comment: are you sure `$_POST['hb']` set set every time ?

Comment: how do you know your `UPDATE` queries work, as you are not checking if the queries succeeded/failed and if there were any rows affected. Depending on your system/settings, your column names may be case sensitive, so `WHERE ID=1` would not work if you column is `id`.

Comment: _1._ **your code is vulnerable to sql injection**

Comment: [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) can reply your question. Try this first.

Comment: my database can get the data, everytime i refresh the table showing different data.

Comment: * problem solve... i just seperate the the php file, make the display file refresh every 3second, and finally the  data can be shown. thx again.